# Profile Mountain Lion's startup

Tags: macos, startup

Recently my Mac mini became quite slow without a real apparent cause. I'd really like to be able to trace down the cause of this slowness, and I'd like to do it myself, not using a program.

Is there a good Mac OS X resource website that could lead me to that?

Comment: Is it slow to start up or in normal operation? In the second case, create a fresh user and log in using that user and see if it's still slow.

Comment: no it's only slow at startup but thing is I would like to be able to trace the cause by monitoring each startup process, like a system profiler or a small script that I would code myself

Answer (score 2):

Couple things to try:

- Start in [verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) (Command + V)

You'll see a narration of the start up processes.

- Open Console and look at your logs.

There's lots of things that can lead to slow startups, but I'd be on the look out for permission and network timeout errors.